# ubuntu server 17.04 login loop console

Tags: login, 17.04, console

I've worked on my Ubuntu server 17.04 for a week now and starting today I've no access to it. When I try to login using SSH the login is denied and when i try to login directly on the Hyper-V VM it logs in successfully then goes back to the login screen ( console, not GUI ).

Is there a way that i could log back on my server?

I've tried to use the recovery but it gets me to the normal boot directly.
I've tried to add the `init=/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` after the grub statement but it doesn't work. It does that to all my users.

Using a live-cd i was able to get some additional informations from my system logs.

```
Sep  4 14:12:02 server systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of gabadmin.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: Started Session 4 of user gabadmin.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Reached target Timers.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Reached target Paths.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Reached target Sockets.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Reached target Basic System.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Reached target Default.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Startup finished in 7ms.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: getty@tty1.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: Stopped Getty on tty1.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Stopped target Default.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Stopped target Basic System.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Stopped target Paths.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Stopped target Sockets.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Reached target Shutdown.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Starting Exit the Session...
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Stopped target Timers.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[2413]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 2423 (kill).
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Sep  4 14:12:06 server systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of gabadmin.
```

if i check with the normal server logging it shows :

```
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of gabadmin.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[1]: Started Session 161 of user gabadmin.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[36312]: Reached target Paths.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[36312]: Reached target Timers.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[36312]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[36312]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[36312]: Reached target Sockets.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[36312]: Reached target Basic System.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[36312]: Reached target Default.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[36312]: Startup finished in 18ms.
Sep  2 22:01:50 server systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Sep  2 22:09:01 server CRON[36634]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Sep  2 22:09:03 server systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Sep  2 22:09:03 server systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Sep  2 22:16:39 server systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt activities...
Sep  2 22:16:41 server systemd[1]: Started Daily apt activities.
Sep  2 22:17:01 server CRON[37149]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep  2 22:18:21 server systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of server.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution !
Basically the Bash binaries were deleted from my computer.

i've used : http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

to try to get access to root and i've found out that there was no bash

--fixed